# Using matrices as basemap and lay over map

Tags: matlab

suppose you have a comprehensive matlab script with a loop that plots the spread of an anmial around the world, starting from a starting point.

That works fine.

but now i don't want just the world as 'base map' but a 'world with values' which i have in a matrix (the sum of all animals in each cell of the world) ?

someone ideas?

Comment: Can you add your code to clarify what you are asking?

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: I don't understand what you actually want to do. I don't know what you mean by the *world as 'base map'* or *a 'world with values'*.